# Using D3 to generate SVG Pie Chart how to vertically align text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Using D3 to generate SVG Pie Chart how to vertically align text like shown in picture.

[image]

The sample code below shows horizontal text and everything I try does not work.

```js
        var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
        var fs = 33;
        if(w > h){
            w = w / 1.5;
        } else {
            h = h / 1.5;
        }
        
        if(w > h){
            fs = h /25;
        } else {
            fs = w /25;
        }
        var padding = {top:20, right:40, bottom:0, left:0},
            w = w - padding.left - padding.right,
            h = h - padding.top  - padding.bottom,
            r = Math.min(w, h)/2,
            rotation = 0,
            oldrotation = 0,
            picked = 100000,
            oldpick = [],
            color = d3.scale.category20();//category20c()
        var data = [
                    {"label":"100",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"}, // padding
                    {"label":"200",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the font?"}, //font-family
                    {"label":"300",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"}, //color
                    {"label":"400",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"}, //font-weight
                    {"label":"500",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"}, //font-size
                    {"label":"600",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"}, //background-color
                    {"label":"700",  "value":1,  "question":"Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"}, //nesting
                    {"label":"GRAND",  "value":1,  "question":"Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"}, //bottom
                    {"label":"",  "value":1,  "question":"What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"}, //sans-serif
                    {"label":"100", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"}, //period
                    {"label":"200", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify an ID?"}, //pound sign
                    {"label":"300", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag holds all of the content people see?"}, //<body>
                    {"label":"400", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates an unordered list?"}, //<ul>
                    {"label":"500", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates the most important heading of your document?"}, //<h1>
                    {"label":"600", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area outside a box?"}, //margin
                    {"label":"700", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for HTML tags?"}, //< >
                    {"label":"", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for CSS rules?"}, // { }
                    {"label":"100", "value":1, "question":"Which HTML tag is used for specifying a paragraph?"}, //<p>
                    {"label":"200", "value":1, "question":"What should always be the very first line of code in your HTML?"}, //<!DOCTYPE html>
                    {"label":"300", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of the metadata tags for your page?"}, //<head>
                    {"label":"400", "value":1, "question":"In CSS, what character separates a property from a value?"}, // colon
                    {"label":"500", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of your CSS code?"}, // <style>
                    {"label":"600", "value":1, "question":"What file extension should you use for your web pages?"}, // .html
                    {"label":"700", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for marking up content and structure on a web page?"}, // HTML
                    {"label":"", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for specifying the design of a web page?"}, // CSS
//                    {"label":"SAMSUNG NOTE5", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for adding functionality to a web page?"}, // JavaScript
//                    {"label":"HP DESKTOP", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for making the edges of a box visible?"}, // border
//                    {"label":"15,000,000$", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol is used at the end of each CSS statement?"},//semi-colon
//                    {"label":"BUGGATI", "value":1, "question":"By default, how wide is a <div> box?"}, //100%
//                    {"label":" GOOGLE JOB", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol do I use to specify multiple CSS selectors in one code block?"} //comma
        ];
        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
            .append("svg")
            .data([data])
            //.style("display", "flex")
            .attr("width",  w + padding.left + padding.right)
            .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);
        var container = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chartholder")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2 + padding.left) + "," + (h/2 + padding.top) + ")");
        var vis = container
            .append("g");
            
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){return 1;});
        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
        // select paths, use arc generator to draw
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "slice");
            
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return color(i); })
            .attr("d", function (d) { return arc(d); });
        // add the text
        arcs.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d){
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle)/2;
                return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius - 10) +")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("font-size", fs)
            .text( function(d, i) {
                return data[i].label;
            });

        container.on("click", spin);
        function spin(d){
            
            container.on("click", null);
            //all slices have been seen, all done
            console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data.length);
            if(oldpick.length == data.length){
                console.log("done");
                container.on("click", null);
                return;
            }
            var  ps       = 360/data.length,
                 pieslice = Math.round(1440/data.length),
                 rng      = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);
                
            rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);
            
            picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360)/ps);
            picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;
            if(oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1){
                d3.select(this).call(spin);
                return;
            } else {
                oldpick.push(picked);
            }
            rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);
            vis.transition()
                .duration(3000)
                .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
                .each("end", function(){
                    //mark question as seen
                    d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
                        .attr("fill", "#111");
                    //populate question
                    d3.select("#question h1")
                        .text(data[picked].question);
                    oldrotation = rotation;
                
                    container.on("click", spin);
                });
        }
        //make arrow
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h/2)+padding.top) + ")")
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M-" + (r*.15) + ",0L0," + (r*.05) + "L0,-" + (r*.05) + "Z")
            .style({"fill":"black"});
        //draw spin circle
        container.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", 0)
            .attr("r", 60)
            .style({"fill":"white","cursor":"pointer"});
        //spin text
        container.append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("SPIN")
            .style({"font-weight":"bold", "font-size":"30px"});
        
        
        function rotTween(to) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
          return function(t) {
            return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
          };
        }
```

```css
    text{
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
    #chart{
        position:absolute;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        text-align: center;
        
        display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */  
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    #question{
        position: absolute;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;   
        top:0;
        left:0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    #question h1{
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
                transform:translate(0,-50%);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wheel of Fortune Bingo</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="question"><h1></h1></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is using [`glyph-orientation-vertical`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/glyph-orientation-vertical). However, I believe that appending separate `<tspan>` elements is easier to control.

So, transform each string into an array of letters, that you append as tspans, in your text selection:

```
textSelection.selectAll(null)
    .data((_,i) => data[i].label)
    .enter()
    .append("tspan")
    .attr("rotate", 90)
    //etc...
```

Here is the result:

```js
var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
        var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
        var fs = 33;
        if(w > h){
            w = w / 1.5;
        } else {
            h = h / 1.5;
        }
        
        if(w > h){
            fs = h /25;
        } else {
            fs = w /25;
        }
        var padding = {top:20, right:40, bottom:0, left:0},
            w = w - padding.left - padding.right,
            h = h - padding.top  - padding.bottom,
            r = Math.min(w, h)/2,
            rotation = 0,
            oldrotation = 0,
            picked = 100000,
            oldpick = [],
            color = d3.scale.category20();//category20c()
        var data = [
                    {"label":"100",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area between the content and its border?"}, // padding
                    {"label":"200",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the font?"}, //font-family
                    {"label":"300",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the color of text?"}, //color
                    {"label":"400",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the boldness of text?"}, //font-weight
                    {"label":"500",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the size of text?"}, //font-size
                    {"label":"600",  "value":1,  "question":"What CSS property is used for changing the background color of a box?"}, //background-color
                    {"label":"700",  "value":1,  "question":"Which word is used for specifying an HTML tag that is inside another tag?"}, //nesting
                    {"label":"GRAND",  "value":1,  "question":"Which side of the box is the third number in: margin:1px 1px 1px 1px; ?"}, //bottom
                    {"label":"",  "value":1,  "question":"What are the fonts that don't have serifs at the ends of letters called?"}, //sans-serif
                    {"label":"100", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify a class?"}, //period
                    {"label":"200", "value":1, "question":"With CSS selectors, what character prefix should one use to specify an ID?"}, //pound sign
                    {"label":"300", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag holds all of the content people see?"}, //<body>
                    {"label":"400", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates an unordered list?"}, //<ul>
                    {"label":"500", "value":1, "question":"In an HTML document, which tag indicates the most important heading of your document?"}, //<h1>
                    {"label":"600", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for specifying the area outside a box?"}, //margin
                    {"label":"700", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for HTML tags?"}, //< >
                    {"label":"", "value":1, "question":"What type of bracket is used for CSS rules?"}, // { }
                    {"label":"100", "value":1, "question":"Which HTML tag is used for specifying a paragraph?"}, //<p>
                    {"label":"200", "value":1, "question":"What should always be the very first line of code in your HTML?"}, //<!DOCTYPE html>
                    {"label":"300", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of the metadata tags for your page?"}, //<head>
                    {"label":"400", "value":1, "question":"In CSS, what character separates a property from a value?"}, // colon
                    {"label":"500", "value":1, "question":"What HTML tag holds all of your CSS code?"}, // <style>
                    {"label":"600", "value":1, "question":"What file extension should you use for your web pages?"}, // .html
                    {"label":"700", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for marking up content and structure on a web page?"}, // HTML
                    {"label":"", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for specifying the design of a web page?"}, // CSS
//                    {"label":"SAMSUNG NOTE5", "value":1, "question":"Which coding language is used for adding functionality to a web page?"}, // JavaScript
//                    {"label":"HP DESKTOP", "value":1, "question":"What CSS property is used for making the edges of a box visible?"}, // border
//                    {"label":"15,000,000$", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol is used at the end of each CSS statement?"},//semi-colon
//                    {"label":"BUGGATI", "value":1, "question":"By default, how wide is a <div> box?"}, //100%
//                    {"label":" GOOGLE JOB", "value":1, "question":"What character symbol do I use to specify multiple CSS selectors in one code block?"} //comma
        ];
        var svg = d3.select('#chart')
            .append("svg")
            .data([data])
            //.style("display", "flex")
            .attr("width",  w + padding.left + padding.right)
            .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);
        var container = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "chartholder")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2 + padding.left) + "," + (h/2 + padding.top) + ")");
        var vis = container
            .append("g");
            
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d){return 1;});
        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);
        // select paths, use arc generator to draw
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
            .data(pie)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "slice");
            
        arcs.append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i){ return color(i); })
            .attr("d", function (d) { return arc(d); });
        // add the text
        arcs.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function(d){
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle)/2;
                return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius - 10) +")";
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .style("font-size", fs)
            .selectAll(null)
            .data((_,i)=>data[i].label)
            .enter()
            .append("tspan")
            .attr("rotate", "90")
            .attr("dx", (_,i)=> i ? "-1.5em" : null)
            .attr("y", 0)
            .text( function(d) {
                return d
            });

        container.on("click", spin);
        function spin(d){
            
            container.on("click", null);
            //all slices have been seen, all done
            console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data.length);
            if(oldpick.length == data.length){
                console.log("done");
                container.on("click", null);
                return;
            }
            var  ps       = 360/data.length,
                 pieslice = Math.round(1440/data.length),
                 rng      = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);
                
            rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);
            
            picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360)/ps);
            picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;
            if(oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1){
                d3.select(this).call(spin);
                return;
            } else {
                oldpick.push(picked);
            }
            rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps/2);
            vis.transition()
                .duration(3000)
                .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
                .each("end", function(){
                    //mark question as seen
                    d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
                        .attr("fill", "#111");
                    //populate question
                    d3.select("#question h1")
                        .text(data[picked].question);
                    oldrotation = rotation;
                
                    container.on("click", spin);
                });
        }
        //make arrow
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h/2)+padding.top) + ")")
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", "M-" + (r*.15) + ",0L0," + (r*.05) + "L0,-" + (r*.05) + "Z")
            .style({"fill":"black"});
        //draw spin circle
        container.append("circle")
            .attr("cx", 0)
            .attr("cy", 0)
            .attr("r", 60)
            .style({"fill":"white","cursor":"pointer"});
        //spin text
        container.append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("y", 15)
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("SPIN")
            .style({"font-weight":"bold", "font-size":"30px"});
        
        
        function rotTween(to) {
          var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
          return function(t) {
            return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
          };
        }
```

```css
text{
        font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:11px;
        pointer-events:none;
    }
    #chart{
        position:absolute;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        text-align: center;
        
        display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */  
        display: flex;
        -webkit-align-items: center; /* Safari 7.0+ */
        align-items: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    #question{
        position: absolute;
        width:100vw;
        height:100vh;   
        top:0;
        left:0;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    #question h1{
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        top:50%;
        -webkit-transform:translate(0,-50%);
                transform:translate(0,-50%);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Wheel of Fortune Bingo</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <div id="question"><h1></h1></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Two observations: first, avoid using the indices of the data array to get the correct string; instead of that, bind the strings themselves as the data. Secondly, I'm passing a string to `data()`, which will convert it in an array. However, that behaviour can change anytime; so, for better reliability, convert the string into an array yourself, for instance using `String.prototype.split()`.